# merge table to get same user_id

Tags: php, mysql, database

i got a employer system ( http://envato.jigowatt.co.uk/demos/phplogin/login.php ) and i would like to add ( voting system, employer daily report, message system )
so i started with the voting system and i did download it from here ( http://absolutephp.wordpress.com/2013/03/23/simple-star-rating-system-using-php-mysql/ )

i did import the ratings table into the employer databaase and made the ratings config work from the employer database ... now how i can make the ratings ID read the users id so the admin can rate employers ?

i am very sorry but it's really an important issues

Comment: are you talking about employer table and rating table? Read more about relations and using joins

Comment: You need to have the user id as a column in your ratings table. Then when selecting the ratings join the 2 tables, ie. `FROM ratings LEFT JOIN users on ratings.userid = employers.id`

Answer (score 0):

i have 2 database ( db1 & db2 )
the db1 is the master database and db2 belong to Private Message system with 2 table as following :

--

### -- Table structure for table `users`

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `avatar` text NOT NULL,
  `signup_date` int(10) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--

### -- Table structure for table `pm`

CREATE TABLE `pm` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `id2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `user1` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `user2` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `message` text NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `user1read` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  `user2read` varchar(3) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

and the db1 is this database [enter link description here](http://major-realestates.com/staff.sql)

so i made the marge so i put the above 2 tables in the db1 now i want it to use the same login_user table so it can run from the same database ... thanks